# Time Series and Statistical Learning methods differences

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, forecasting

I am trying to understand the Time Series and Forecasting methods.

I have this basic theoretical question about this:

Why "Time Series" is NOT included on the Contents of, for example, the book "The Elements of Statistical Learning" Tibshirani - Hastie or so many others similar books?

There are a lot of specific books for Time Series, but isn't it an Statistical Learning method?